# How to move a canvas built wave form along an x axis

Tags: javascript, canvas, waveform

I have drawn a wave form that can be manipulated by the user.  The wave form easily moves up and down the y axis of the canvas, but I am having difficulty moving wave form along the x axis.

I have added a [working copy to codePen](http://codepen.io/m055up/pen/xGNjZa)

The HTML:

```
 <div id="oscilloscope">
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>

<div class="dials">

  <section class="model-15">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input id="sin" type="checkbox" value="sin">
      <label></label>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div id="focus">
    <input id="blur" class="knob" data-width="50" data-fgColor="#AA3939" data-min="0" data-max="15" data-displayPrevious=true value="0">
    <div class="label_focus">Focus</div>
  </div>

  <div id="intensity">
    <input id="intense" class="knob" data-width="50" data-fgColor="#AA7439" data-min="1" data-max="9" data-displayPrevious=true value="9">
    <div class="label_intensity">Intensity</div>
  </div>

  <div id="xmove">
    <input id="xpos" class="knob" data-width="50" data-min="-20" data-max="420" data-displayPrevious=true value="200" data-fgColor="#F890C8">
    <div class="label_xpos">X-Pos</div>
  </div>

  <div id="ymove">
    <input id="ypos" class="knob" data-width="50" data-min="-20" data-max="320" data-displayPrevious=true value="150" data-fgColor="#ad648c">
    <div class="label_ypos">Y-Pos</div>
  </div>

  <div id="volts">
    <input id="sin-f" class="knob" data-width="100" data-min="1" data-max="50" data-displayPrevious=true value="5">
    <div class="label_volts">Volts/Div</div>
  </div>

  <div id="time_delay">
    <input id="period" class="knob" data-width="100" data-fgColor="#FF4D4D" data-min="1" data-max="25" data-displayPrevious=true value="1">
    <div class="label_delay">Delay</div>
  </div>

  <div id="volts_ch2">
    <input id="amps" class="knob" data-width="100" data-min="1" data-displayPrevious=true value="5" data-fgColor="#66cc66">
    <div class="label_volts2">Volts/Div</div>

  </div>
```

with the main element of the JS code that I've been working on.

```
 function drawWave() {

ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(25, 255, 50, 0.8)';  //sets waveform stroke colour & Size
console.log ("sinFreq: " + sinFrequency);
example = intensity.value/10;
ctx.globalAlpha= example;
ctx.shadowBlur = fuzz.value; 


// omega = 2 * pi * f
function getOmega(frequency) {
  return 2 * Math.PI * frequency;
}

// pixel = 2 * Math.PI * frequency * period / canvas.width
function getPixel(frequency) {
  return getOmega(frequency) * period / (cx.value/.5);
}

var sin_pixel = getPixel(sinFrequency);

function getWavePoints(count, pixel, triangle_func) {
  var points = []; //points array

  for (var i = 0, len = count; i < len; i++) {
    points.push(triangle_func(pixel * i) * factor + yPosition); //this moves the wavform along y axis, but it is an array 

  }

  return points;
}
```

// Below is where the x-pos move should function

```
 function drawPoints(pixel, triangle_func) {
      var path = getWavePoints(canvas.width, pixel, triangle_func);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, path[0]);

  for (var i = 0, len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(i, path[i]);
  }

  ctx.stroke();
}

    if (isDrawSin) {
      drawPoints(sin_pixel, function(x){return Math.sin(x);});
    }
  }

  function getFactor() { //the function adjusts the wave height (amplitude)
    return canvas.height / amp;  
  }
```

I want to move the whole waveform left and right but not increase the frequency of the wave form, when doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What You are trying to do is changing the `phase` of Your periodic function. Generally, periodic functions look like this:

```
y = amplitude * f(2 * pi * frequency + phase) + yoffset
```

... where `f` is `sin`, `cos` etc. When moving up and down, You change `yoffset`, as You do using Your `yPosition` variable. Moving the graph from left to right can be achieved by changing the `phase` value.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but the problem I'm having is still persisting.  I can get the waveform to track left and right but the frequency of the wave increases and decreases, in doing so.  Do you have any idea how I maybe able to effect the 'moveTo' coordinates off the canvas?  Updated codepen...

Comment: That's because You don't need to *multiply* by xPosition, but You need to *add* it, like this: `points.push(triangle_func(pixel * (i - xPosition)) * factor + yPosition);`